# Using Rails' CanCan gem to handle a has_and_belongs_to_many situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, cancan

I have the following:

- User model that `has_and_belongs_to_many` Restaurants and vice-versa.
- Restaurant model `that has_and_belongs_to_many` Meals and vice-versa.

In my `ability.rb` file, I want to specify that a user can only manage meals of restaurants he "has_and_belongs_to" (i.e. restaurants in `user.restaurants`).

I have this right now:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    # a user can only manage meals of restaurants he has access to
    can :manage, Meal do |meal| 
      meal.restaurant_ids & user.restaurant_ids #...this doesn't work...
    end
  end
end
```

What's the best way to do this?

I've consulted https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks but I still don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "&" operator on an array will always return an array. An empty array is not considered false, so it will always pass. Try checking if it is present (not blank).

```
(meal.restaurant_ids & user.restaurant_ids).present?
```

Comment: Neat - thanks for responding. I'll try this out soon. Out of curiosity, where is this present?() method defined? It's not in Ruby Array's doc...

Comment: ah found it here.... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F :]

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old question. If I am doing the `:create` action on a form and I'm check-boxing which restaurants the meal belongs to, is it possible for me to spoof the system by sending in 1 restaurant ID that is owned by me and 1 that isn't? The condition above will return true because one correct ID is present.